# VBA: Code within INI file

Tags: vba, excel, ini

I am currently making a Macro that can send out a bunch of emails with attachments all at once. I did this in outlook, but I'd like to redo it within Excel, so any user can simply press a button on the spreadsheet and it emails out the reports. My issue is certain reports have a special subject for example (Cabana Arrivals till (6 months from date)) in outlook I simply put dateadd("M",6,Date) after the subject my issue is I don't want to 'hard code' this within the loop. My question is when VBA reads the INI file, is there anyway to make the key's data active? So when it reads this key:

> Special Instructions=format(dateadd("M",6,date), "MM/DD/YYYY")

the subject will now be "Cabana Arrivals Till 04/07/2016" or is there a totally different way I need to look at this? Any help is appreciated wasn't sure on how to even find the answer to this as I've never heard of doing it before.

Comment: Which VBA host is reading the INI file? Why is an INI file even required?

Comment: Excel is reading it with the GetPrivateProfileString and I am using ini to make it easier to change in the future, and the overall project is using ini (this is only a small branch off a larger project).

Comment: Why can't Excel just automate Outlook directly?

Comment: It is I'm using the INI file to store the to,attachments, subject, ect. The 'section name' is the subject and the keys are 'to', 'attachments', and 'special instructions' my problem is the reports I send out some have a specific date in the subject name as well as the report name. I wanted to use the 'special instructions' key to store code that i want to help make the subject, and then excel would add the section name and the outcome of the code in the special instructions key to make the subject line.

Comment: It sound s like you are trying to write VBA program code in the .ini file and have that code execute at runtime?  I am not even sure if this is possible but, if it were, it would probably open up some undesirable possibilities.  At best, someone could alter the .ini file in a way that causes your program to crash.  At worst they could add malicious program code to the .ini file.  Do you have the ability (permissions) to change the VBA code?  If yes, then there are probably a few different ways you could approach this.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I just was looking at it totally wrong! Instead of passing code through the ini I should of just passed the function's variables through as I'll only ever use the dateadd function.

Answer (score 0):

Date add would be the only function used so create a key called 'subject date add' and set it equal to the interval (m,d,y) and the # of days/months/year. It should look like ('subject date add' = m,6) split on , and remove spaces for date grab the files modify date. If key does not exist skip.